# Passing a parameter with an onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parameters, onclick

I'm working on a project with API calls. Basically, I need to be able to pass a parameter to a function with jQuery when a certain button is clicked.

I am working on a project that calls an API to display class buttons to a user.

Each button will be generated based on the presence of a classId, which is called in a jQuery file:

jQuery:

```
function getCourses() {
    $.ajax({
        url: apisource + "/courses",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        let dataLength = Object.keys(data).length;
        for (let i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
            courseId = data["courses"][i].id; //this is the important part
            nameOfClass = data["courses"][i].name;
            let classButton = ('<button type=\'button\' class=\'classButton\' onclick=\'javascript:getStudentsInCourses(' + courseId + ');\'>' + nameOfClass + '</button>'); 

            $('#classButtonContainer').append(classButton);
    }

}) 
}
getCourses();

function getStudentsInCourses(currentCourseId) {

    console.log("current course id: " + currentCourseId);

    $.ajax({
        url: apisource + "/course=" + currentCourseId + "/students",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log("here are the students");
        console.log(data);
}}
```

What I want to do here is that when a user clicks on a class button, the courseId for that button becomes the "currentCourseId", and is able to be passed to getStudentsInCourses so that it can call the students for that course. I've been scouring the web for the proper way to pass that variable but no method has worked so far. Does anyone have any pointers for how to pass this variable?

So it should be something like this:
when a user clicks one of the classButtons, that button's courseId will pass to the "getStudentsInCourses" function as the "currentCourseId"

Comment: I think if I understand correctly what you are trying to do here, you can set the id of each button to be the respective courseId. Then, you can set the same on-click listener for all of your buttons but inside the on-click listener, call the getStudentsInCourses function and as a parameter, pass the id of the button that was clicked.

Comment: What's wrong with your code ? Did you get an error ?

Comment: The 'currentCourseId' that is being passed to 'getStudentsInCourses' is always the courseId of the last button that was generated, not the button that gets clicked.

Comment: The only issue I see with this logic is that you are trying to loop based upon the number of keys in the data, rather than on the number of elements in data.courses.  https://jsfiddle.net/398f1gsL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jquery you can use the click event to execute a logic.
Do not forget to call the function before the click event below.

```
//your functions
$('.classButtons').on('click', function(){
   const id = $(this).attr('id');
   //now call your function with the id
   getStudentsInCourses(id);
});
```

If you have questions or misunderstood your request let me know =)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working for me. Perhaps, it's your `courseId` variable that's causing an issue ? Are you sure it's not the same id ?

```
courseId = data["courses"][i].id;
```

```js
function getCourses() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let classButton = ('<button type=\'button\' class=\'classButton\' onclick=\'javascript:getStudentsInCourses(' + i + ');\'>Test ' + i + '</button>');
    $('#classButtonContainer').append(classButton);
  }
}

getCourses();

function getStudentsInCourses(currentCourseId) {
  console.log("current course id: " + currentCourseId);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="classButtonContainer"></div>
```